# Using php and calling values from mySQL I am trying to call every 16 rows that contain the METAL GOLD

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

Here is the code I am tring to use:

```
<?php
function get_silver_time()
{
     $goldquery = mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, time,metal
    FROM ( 
        SELECT @row :=0) r, metal_price 
    ) ranked 
WHERE rownum % 16 = 1
WHERE metal= 'GOLD'  
"); 


         while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $goldquery )) 
 { 

    echo "'" . date('g A', strToTime($result['time'])) . "'" . ", " ;  
 } 

         }
?>
```

This Returns This Error:

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/bellsnet/public_html/chart.php on line 125

Without trying to filter out the METAL type my code seems to work:

```
<?php
function get_silver_time()
{
     $goldquery = mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, time,metal
    FROM ( 
        SELECT @row :=0) r, metal_price 
    ) ranked 
WHERE rownum % 16 = 1

"); 


         while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $goldquery )) 
 { 

    echo "'" . date('g A', strToTime($result['time'])) . "'" . ", " ;  
 } 

         }
?>
```

And it returns this:

'1 AM', '11 PM', '1 AM', '3 AM', '6 AM', '8 AM', '10 AM', '12 PM', '2 PM', '4 PM', '6 PM', '8 PM', '10 PM', '12 AM', '2 AM', '4 AM', '6 AM', '8 AM', '10 AM', '12 PM', '2 PM', '4 PM', '6 PM', '8 PM', '10 PM', '12 AM', '2 AM', '4 AM', '6 AM', '8 AM', '10 AM', '12 PM', '2 PM', '4 PM',

Any Help Would Be Appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Just to be sure, what exactly do you want? Do you want to select the rows that contain the metal gold and then return every 16th row, or do you want to select every 16th row and then only return those that contain the metal gold?

Comment: I wanted to select the rows that contain the metal gold and then return every 16th row, sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it make sense, then, to filter the FROM sub-query on the metal you want?

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, time,metal
    FROM ( 
        SELECT @row :=0) r, metal_price 
    WHERE metal = 'GOLD'
) ranked 
WHERE rownum % 16 = 1
```

Then the "ranked" table should return a result set containing only GOLD rows, and the rownum should count only those rows, allowing you to select every sixteenth GOLD row with your modulus filter.

Comment: THAT's IT!!!! Thank You So Much, SOmetimes We Just Need Another Eye TO Look at Our Work. I really appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 1):

After calling `mysql_query` you should always check if query was successful:

```
if(!$goldquery){
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

This will print you that you have error in your SQL statement. In your case it is doubled `WHERE` keyword, conditions in where clause should be separated by `AND` or `OR`, depending on what you want to check.

But if You want to select every 16th row only from `GOLD`, your second WHERE condition should be moved into `ranked` temp table, so it should look like this:

```
$goldquery = mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, time, metal
    FROM 
        (SELECT @row :=0) r,
        metal_price 
    WHERE
        metal= 'GOLD'
    ) ranked 
WHERE rownum % 16 = 1
");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your `WHERE` clause.

```
 $goldquery = mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, time,metal
    FROM ( 
        SELECT @row :=0) r, metal_price 
    ) ranked 
WHERE rownum % 16 = 1
AND metal= 'GOLD'  
");
```

Note the change in the line containing 'GOLD' to use `AND` instead of `WHERE`.